# The xml root is repeating multiple time in sql?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I wanted the output of my xml to look like this:

```
<CustomConfigurationSteps>
  <CustomConfigurations>
    <CustomConfiguration SiteURL="abc">
      <CustomElements>
        <CustomElement Type="Searchtype" unit="3" price="5">
          <ClassValue>AZSupreme</ClassValue>
        </CustomElement>
      </CustomElements>
      <CustomElements>
        <CustomElement Type="Searchtype" unit="3" price="5">
          <ClassVaue>AZSupreme</ClassVaue>
        </CustomElement>
      </CustomElements>
    </CustomConfiguration>
  </CustomConfigurations>
</CustomConfigurationSteps>
```

I tried the below logic, but its not giving me the exact output.

```
DECLARE @xml xml

SET @xml = (SELECT 
                config.SiteURL AS '@SiteURL',
                (SELECT 
                     CustomConfiguration.Type AS '@Type',
                     CustomConfiguration.[PackageName] AS '@unit',
                     CustomConfiguration.[UseExecute] AS '@price',
                     ClassValue
                 FOR XML PATH('CustomElement'), TYPE) AS CustomElements
            FROM 
                [dbo].[CustomConfigurationSteps] AS CustomConfiguration WITH (nolock)
            INNER JOIN 
                WebSiteConfiguration  AS config WITH (nolock) ON config.ConfigurationID = CustomConfiguration.[ConfigurationID]
            WHERE
                CustomConfiguration.[ConfigurationID] = 9
            FOR XML path ('CustomConfiguration'), TYPE)
    --set @xml1=( SELECT @xml  FOR XML path ('CustomConfiguration') ,type)

SELECT @xml  
FOR XML path ('CustomConfigurations'), ROOT ('CustomConfigurationSteps')
```

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: i am using sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this (although this looks a little odd, especially the repeating `<CustomElements>` node.

A *mockup table* to simulate your issue:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE([Type] VARCHAR(100),unit int, price DECIMAL(10,4),ClassValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Searchtype 1',1,11,'AZSupreme 1')
                      ,('Searchtype 2',2,22,'AZSupreme 2');
```

--The query

```
SELECT 'abc' AS [CustomConfiguration/@SiteURL]
      ,(
            SELECT t.[Type] AS [CustomElement/@Type]
                  ,t.unit AS [CustomElement/@unit]
                  ,t.price AS [CustomElement/@pricee]
                  ,t.ClassValue [CustomElement/ClassValue]
            FROM @tbl t
            FOR XML PATH('CustomElements'),TYPE
       ) AS CustomConfiguration
FOR XML PATH('CustomConfigurations'),ROOT('CustomConfigurationSteps');
```

Comment: I tried this but this still the CustomConfiguration is repeating

Comment: @user3675493 Sorry, but you do not show enough... In my code the `<CustomConfiguration>` (which you claim to be repeating) is the *column name* of the inner Xml-Select. As long as there is no additional step involved, where this query is called more often than once, this should not repeat... Please try to use my code to set up a [mcve]. Some *stand-alone* code sample, we can copy to our machines and run to reproduce your issue.